# how to get a character from a particular position in a 2-D array

Tags: java, arrays, character

I have a 2-D array called ITdouble, and I want the 1-D array I to be assigned to the character in the position l of the 2-D array.

I have tried the following code:

```
double[][] ITdouble = new double[32][2];
double[] I = new double [32];
for (int i=0; i<IT.length; i++)
    {

    for(int l=0; l<5; l++)
        {
           I[l]=ITdouble[i][0].charAt(l);
        }
}
```

However an error "Double cannot be dereferenced" is being shown. Is there any other simple way to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

`charAt` is a `String` method. Based on the error you got, your `ITdouble` array is a `double` array, so you can't call that method (or any other method, since `double` is primitive) on it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your 2D array is by type `double`. You are trying to pass in a `char` into a `double` array. Furthermore, `.charAt` is a method for `String` type.

I suggest you provide more information on the data types of your variables. It will be easier for people here to help you.

**Note that:** a char can only hold a single character. A double needs more than one character, even if I tell you how to convert a `char` into `double`, you would left with only a single digit.

---

```
//Position of 2D array to extract data
int x1=3;
int y1=2;

//Convert double to string
String str = Double.toString(ITdouble[x1][y1]); 

//Place single character into 1D array
for(int x=0; x<I.length(); x++)
    I[x] = str.charAt(x);
```

Since you want to let `I` store all the single characters of a double value like `3.14159` into `3` `.` `1` `4` `1` `5` `9`. You should declare your 1D array `I` as char instead of double.

---

**Some comments on your codes:**

Using the naming convention for variables, it is advisable that you use a meaningful name for your variables. Variables should start with lowercase. In this case `I` and `ITdouble` didn't follow the naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes my arrays are both of type double. Would there be any other way of doing this ?

Comment: @user2675041 Let me ask you. Is it that you want another 1D array `I` to store the first row of values from your 2D array?

Comment: No, I want to split each character in the row from the 2D array

Comment: @user2675041 I think this is what you are asking for.